# How to rotate secrets in an untrusted Kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes, authentication, openid

I'm automating the provisioning of Kubernetes environments for developer users.  I'd like to regularly rotate the resources of kind 'secret' that are inside these environments.  Furthermore, I'd **only** like to provision OR re-provision those rotated secrets in these environments if the user currently should have access to those secrets (because the user will be able to use kubectl on the environment to read anything inside it).  Ideally, I would retrieve these secrets from a secret manager like [gcloud secret manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) or [akeyless](https://www.akeyless.io/) which could do the rotation for me.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to do this without putting the credential to perform the rotation inside the untrusted user environment - which seems like a terrible idea.  I could ask the environment to reach out to my automation for the rotated secrets, but (I think) there is no way to verify their identity unless they reauthenticate.

I could ask the user to authenticate and re-request an environment (or just the secrets) whenever the secrets rotate, but this limits how often I can rotate without driving the user crazy.

Is there some standard way that people do this kind of thing?

If it helps, the user authenticates with my provisioning automation using an OpenId.

Comment: Of the top of my head, I'd suggest to use kubernetes-authentication for vault and use a [SecretStore](https://external-secrets.io/latest/api/secretstore/) of external-secrets with the developer's service account. However this assumes a "one namespace per developer and one developer per namespace" policy.

Comment: I guess the key insight here might be to use a developer service account to retrieve the credentials when they rotate.  Like many good ideas, it seems obvious in retrospect.  Thank you!

Comment: To be precise, you can use ANY service account  of a cluster to connect to the Kubernetes API via kubectl...